# LWC save and deploy in one step with VSCode

Tags: lightning-web-components

Coming from a non-salesforce JS background. How does one save and deploy a LWC component in one step. It's really time consuming that I have to first save and then go to the command palette to deploy my code? Is there a faster way to do it?

ENV - VSCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a setting in the extension to `auto-deploy on save` if that's what you're looking for.

Navigate to File > Preferences > Settings then expand the Extensions drop-down and you'll see [image: this]

Alternatively, you can enable this directly in the settings.json file with the following line:

```
"salesforcedx-vscode-core.push-or-deploy-on-save.enabled": true
```

Hope this helps/answers your question.